# TypeORM select entity, except some, where id not equal condition

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I Have two entities:

```
    @Entity()
    export class Point {
    
         @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
         id: string;
    
         // some other stuff
 
    }


    @Entity()
    export class Product {
    
         @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
         id: string;
    
         @IsOptional()
         @ManyToMany(() => Point)
         @JoinTable()
         prohibitedToSaleOn: Point[];
    
    }
```

I want to get products, where any object from `prohibitedToSaleOn` (array of `Point`'s) fulfills the condition

> point.id != {idWhatIWant}

So, in final I want to get all product, not banned from sales in selected point. I do something like this:

```
    return this.productRepository.createQueryBuilder('product')
        .leftJoin('product.prohibitedToSaleOn', 'point')
        .where('point.id != :id', {id})
        .getMany();
```

But it doesn't work (it should not at all)

I need help with the right request. Thanks =)

> P.S. I use PostgreSQL

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need to use query builder. [Here](https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations) you can find the description of the alternative way to write joins using relations.

To filter them by id not being equal to the one you provide (`.where('point.id != :id', {id})`), you can write something like `find({where: {id: Not(id)}})`, where `Not` is imported from TypeORM.

Answer (score 5):

I find that the most simple way to do this is to use `typeorm`'s `Not` Operator, like this:

```
return this.productRepository.find( { where: id: Not('some_id') } );
```

Documentation about `Not`:

Find Options Operator. Used to negate expression. Example: { title: not("hello") } will return entities where title not equal to "hello".

Read more [here](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options#advanced-options)

Answer (score 4):

try to move `WHERE` condition in to `join` level

```
return this.productRepository.createQueryBuilder('product')
        .leftJoin('product.prohibitedToSaleOn', 'point', 'point.id != :id', {id})
        .getMany();
```

this query should return all products contained in `prohibitedToSaleOn` join table except for the specified point id.

If you need products that are not banned from sales at the selected point and products that have never been banned, you need query like this:

```
return this.productRepository.createQueryBuilder('product')
        .leftJoin('product.prohibitedToSaleOn', 'point', '(point.id != :id OR point.id IS NULL)', {id})
        .getMany();
```